# org.springframework package cannot be imported

Tags: spring, spring-nature

As the topic says I cannot import this package in my web dynamic project using SpringSource Tool Suite.The command Spring Tools --> Add Spring Project Nature has been already executed.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What kind of project did you create? Is it a Maven project? If so, you need to make sure that you are importing 'at least' the spring-context dependency like so

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

(or whatever version you want to use)

[EDIT]

Since as you say, you are using a Dynamic Web Project through this example -> http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html, you need to physically add the following jar files to your `WEB-INF/lib` folder

```
antlr-runtime-3.0
commons-logging-1.0.4
org.springframework.asm-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.beans-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.context-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.core-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.expression-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.web-3.0.0.M3
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.0.M3
```

You should have the following:

[image: lib folder]

Adding the 'Spring Project Nature' does not add the dependencies for you, but only instructs the IDE that this project is using Spring.

Comment: It is a Dynamic Web Project.Where should I add the xml above?I see a difference with an example I downloaded from sts dashboard.My project's Web App Libraries is empty.I have downloaded all the jars of the framework but I can't add them in my Web App Libraries.

Comment: This is the tutorial page I am trying to follow : http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-mvc-tutorial-1.html

Comment: Ok, so you are not using Maven and you simply need to add the libs to your project :) Let me edit my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Use maven.it automatically adds the necessary jar files.otherwise u need to manually do it.you can have a look at this http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-convert-java-web-project-to-maven-project/
to migrate an existing project into maven

OR

```
You can manually add the necessary jar files.
Right click on the spring project>>
properties>>
java build path>>
libraries>>Add jars
```

:)